# C++ : Copy-constructing from different instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, enums, copy-constructor

I would like to be able to copy-construct a `Particle<Color::X>` using a differently-"colored" instance. Different instantiations might contain a very distinct set of members, but they all have any number of members in common (exemplified below by `intensity`) which must be copied by the ctor.

The ctor in question must, of course, not accept objects of types that are not instantiations of `Particle`.

There could be an unbounded number of members in `Color`, so it's not practical to hand-code constructors accepting every single variant.

Should I use SFINAE, or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

```cpp
enum class Color
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
};

template <enum Color>
struct Particle
{
    int intensity;

    Particle(int i) : intensity{i} {};
};

auto main() -> int
{
    Particle<Color::RED> p1{42};
    // Particle<Color::BLUE> p2(p1); <- How do I make this compile?
}
```

Comment: why do you think you need to SFINAE?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Having a hard time figuring out how to do it with straight-up templates. I have a vague intuition type traits or SFINAE might help me here, but I'm clearly no expert.

Comment: Nitpic: Something is only a *copy constructor* if it accepts the same type. A one parameter constructor can be called a converting constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a copy constructor that accepts instances of other instantiations then you just need a copy constructor that accepts instances of any instantiation:

```
enum class Color
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
};

template <Color c>
struct Particle
{
    int intensity;

    Particle(int i) : intensity{i} {};

    template <Color other_c>
    Particle(const Particle<other_c>& other) : intensity{other.intensity} {};
};

int main() {
    Particle<Color::RED> p1{42};
    Particle<Color::BLUE> p2(p1); 
}
```

As Caleth points out in a comment, strictly speaking its a converting constructor when it converts one type to another. A copy constructor of type `T` accepts `T`s.

---

Note that in your code the template parameter is unnamed. I suppose this was part of the confusion. In your code you actually have no way to know of what `Color` a given instantiation of `Particle` is without using a trait. Not even inside the template definition you can access the particles color, because it has no name. I changed this above. Though if you do not want to waste a member just to store the `Color` of the `Particle` but want to deduce it from a given instantiation you can do this:

```
template <typename T> constexpr Color particle_color;
template <Color c> constexpr Color particle_color<Particle<c>> = c;
```

Usage is for example:

```
static_assert( particle_color<decltype(p2)> == Color::BLUE);
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zjTfb1G7e)

Comment: Ah! I tried getting this to work in many different ways, but it seems my template syntax is lacking. First thing I tried was `template <enum Color> Particle(const Particle<Color>& p)`, which understandably didn't work. Glad to hear I won't be using SFINAE for this *shudders*.

Comment: I have a hard time reading SO since the SE change so I read just bits of words nowadays. Would a `static_assert` be appropriate in response to "_Should I use SFINAE, or is there a simpler way to achieve this?_"? (I am actually incapble of reading code late at night because of the change they made to the site)

Comment: @Talmid maybe you got confused by your template parameter not having a name. Without changing the template you would actually do need a trait to know of what `Color` a given instantiation of `Particle` is. Even inside the template definition you currently cannot access it, because it has no name

Comment: @TedLyngmo there is no sfinae needed, so also no static assert. (unless OP actually wants more that wasn't mentioned yet)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks. It's odd to have to look at bits of code, memoize, look again, try to fit stuff together. It feels like I can't do good here anymore. :-(

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I would love to see how that would work (using the trait), could definitely learn something from that implementation!

Comment: @TedLyngmo you mean the different font? At first I liked it, after a while now I am not sure anymore.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, the font and the sizes. It's like the first people that made this site did _not_ get everything wrong. How strange would that be?

I now have to hunt skilled User Script people to _hopefully_ get me a tool to be able to participate.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I understood correctly there are ways to change it https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364263/358287. I'll give it a try soon, now that you mention it I realize how painful it is actually

Comment: @Talmid let me see if I can get that into the answer somehow

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Cheers! I'm one of the posters there :-) (I just came late into the game - odd clock and all)

Comment: @TedLyngmo you might want to check out [Why change fonts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407551/5987)

Comment: @MarkRansom I like that there's another thread about the change. I _tried_ to find a remedy to the current pain in the posts you linked to too, but I couldn't find it. If there's a setting or something else that I can do, I will. I've never liked a site as much as I like SO - but _fighting it_ kills me.

Comment: @Talmid took a bit longer because I just learned that we can partially specialize variable templates since C++14 :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I know saying this is frowned upon around these parts, but what the heck: Thank you for spending your valuable time answering this question, and then going above and beyond its original scope. I wish you all the best! :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Somehow I was fooled by my first impression and I wanted to belive that something changed for good. Now that I managed to change it feels like a big relieve. Its a little strange that I have to install a browser plugin to read without pain, but if its that, then its that. Some things we can change (fonts) others we cant ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 U+2661 <= (pasting going wrong) Facit:  ♡

Comment: @Talmid thanks for the question, I learned something by writing an answer.